# Position Digits Sum (Sum of digits in two numbers based on their position)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I was working on a practice problem in a website and got stuck at a point.

The question is:

> **Position Digits Sum**
>
> The program must accept two positive integers as the input and then
>   print the sum of their unit digits, tenth digits and so on.
>
> Input Format: The first line will contain A and B separated by a
>   space.
>
> Output Format: The first line will contain the sum of unit digits,
>   tenth digits and so on with the values separated by a space.
>
> Boundary Conditions: 1 <= A,B <= 9999999
>
> Example Input/Output 1: Input: 23 49
>
> Output: 12 6
>
> Example Input/Output 2: Input: 12456 687
>
> Output: 13 13 10 2 1

Well I solved the problem but out of 6 test cases (which are hidden) 5 cases passed and 1 didn't.

This is my code:

```
a,b = input().split()
assert 1<=len(a)<=7 and 1<=len(b)<=7
assert a.isdigit() == True and b.isdigit() == True
if len(a)>1 and len(b)>1:
    assert a[0] != '0' and b[0] != '0'
h = []
m = []
def pp(a,b):
    c = []
    for i in range(1,len(a)+1):
        x = int(a[-i])+int(b[-i])
        c.append(x)
    return c
if len(a)==len(b):
    g = pp(a,b)
    y = [str(i) for i in g]
    for i in range(0,len(y)-1):
        y[0] = y[0]+' '+y[1]
        y.remove(y[1])
    print(y[0])
if len(a)>len(b):
    d = abs(len(a)-len(b))
    for i in range(0,d):
        h.append(a[i])
        r = a.replace(a[0:d],'')
    p = pp(r,b)
    p = p+h[::-1]
    t = [str(i) for i in p]
    for i in range(0,len(t)-1):
        t[0] = t[0]+' '+t[1]
        t.remove(t[1])
    print(t[0])
if len(a)<len(b):
    d = abs(len(a)-len(b))
    for i in range(0,d):
        m.append(b[i])
        u = b.replace(b[0:d],'')
    q = pp(a,u)
    q = q + m[::-1]
    e = [str(i) for i in q]
    for i in range(0,len(e)-1):
        e[0] = e[0]+' '+e[1]
        e.remove(e[1])
    print(e[0])
```

I am a beginner, so I only used simple python code which made it to too long.
I checked but didn't get what is wrong in it. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be done in very simplified way using [`itertools.zip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) in Python 3.x ( equivalent of [`itertools.izip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) in Python 2.7) as:

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> a = 123
>>> b = 67891

>>> [sum(map(int, x))for x in zip_longest(str(a)[::-1], str(b)[::-1], fillvalue=0)]
[4, 11, 9, 7, 6]
```

---

**Explanation:** with step to step intermediate results in the above *list comprehension* expression:

1. Type-casted `int` values to `str` in order to make them iterable. Reversed both the iterables so that they could be iterated in parallel with the correct power of 10 (required in next step).

   ```
   >>> str(a)[::-1]
   '321'
   ```
2. Then used them with [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) in order to iterate both the iterables in parallel. For example:

   ```
   >>> list(zip_longest(str(a)[::-1], str(b)[::-1], fillvalue=0))
   [('3', '1'), ('2', '9'), ('1', '8'), (0, '7'), (0, '6')]
   ```
3. Using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), type-casted each string value in the above sub-list back to `int` as:

   ```
   >>> list(map(int, ('3', '1')))
   [3, 1]
   ```
4. Then, using [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum), added values in the above list:

   ```
   >>> sum([3, 1])
   4
   ```

Comment: I did the same mistake at first (when I _wanted_ to use `zip_longest`, then switched to `zfill`). But `zip_longest` is still good, if you reverse the digits as you finally did.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre My "+1" is already there. And thanks for correcting me at the first place.

Comment: my "+1" is there for your answer too for making it a one-liner and using `itertools.zip_longest`

Answer (score 2):

I didn't analyse your code in depth, but it contains invalid constructs like here:

```
for i in range(0,len(y)-1):
    y[0] = y[0]+' '+y[1]
    y.remove(y[1])
```

here you're changing `y` while iterating over it, for instance.

Me, I would split, then compute the longest integer first, to zero-fill value, then interleave digits together (but starting by the end, hence the reverse operation) sum and convert back to string to pass to `join`

```
import itertools

s = "12456 687"

numbers = s.split()
max_digit = max(len(x) for x in numbers)
numbers = [x.zfill(max_digit) for x in numbers]

# at this point: numbers = ['12456', '00687']

v = " ".join(reversed([str(int(a)+int(b)) for a,b in zip(*numbers)]))
print(v)
```

result:

```
13 13 10 2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.*;

public class Hello
{
public static void main(String[] args)

{

//Your Code Here

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int a = scan.nextInt();
int b = scan.nextInt();
int d1,d2,digit;
while(a>0 || b>0)
{
    d1 = a%10;
    d2 = b%10;
    digit = d1+d2;
    a = a/10;
    b = b/10;
    System.out.print(digit + " ");
}
```

}

}

This is the correct code for Position Digits Sum